# SharePoint 2013 designer workflow created documents inside library shows blank word document

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, document-template

I have one list and one library. The requirement is when any list item gets created automatically the 2013 designer workflow will create a corresponding record inside the library. The library uses one docuemnt template over the content type "Documents" and the document template consumes some of the field value or metadata inside it from the library fields.

When we manually create a item inside the document library by filling out the mandatory fields , the created record corresponding document gets created and if I open the document , then it opens successfully with the content. When the Workflow creates the new item inside the same library by filling out the required metadata , the corresponding document opens with blank content.

Note: I am using create item action in workflow to create new record inside the library.

Kindly guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my SharePoint. Even when I have set the template, workflow will create an empty document。

In the workflow, by design, workflow uses the default document template to create new files.